# how get JSON response of object index value using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

My JSON text is

```
[{
        "album_name" : "marriage",
        "album_image" : "images/abc.jpg"
    }, {
        "album_name" : "holiday",
        "album_image" : "images/holi.jpg"
    }
]
```

In that i need to get index value of each object. I fetched above values using for loop and appended dynamically. My requirement is when i click on each item i need to pass that index value of that object in onclick function.

Comment: what do you mean by index value? as in you need holiday, image_url ??

Comment: above array having 2 objects, i need object index value when loop in that section object, and i need to pass that index value in another function.

Comment: Please help me here http://jsfiddle.net/o77uLru7/2/

Answer (score 1):

Following json object

```
 var json = [{"album_name":"marriage","album_image":"images/abc.jpg"},
             {"album_name":"holiday","album_image":"images/holi.jpg"}];
```

if you want to get any index value then you can get this way

```
console.log(json[0].album_name); // means 0 index album_name key value
```

use `forEach` function to iterate JSON object,

```
var json = [{"album_name":"marriage","album_image":"images/abc.jpg"},
            {"album_name":"holiday","album_image":"images/holi.jpg"}];

json.forEach(function(object, index){
 console.log('Index ==>' + index, ' Object data' + object);
 //or specific key value of object
 console.log(object.album_name);
});
```

Comment: Supply a description and this answer would be perfect.

Comment: @MixedVeg no need 2 loops, see this http://jsfiddle.net/o77uLru7/4/ and you have used `json` for loop variable that is json object

Comment: Thanks @Girish I dnt know where my mind was that time

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this

```
   $.each(json, function(i, obj) {  
      $.each(obj, function(index, value){
        console.log(index);
      });
  });
```

And here is [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/oeLd8q9b/)

Comment: @MixedVeg: plz go through with following article http://www.metaltoad.com/blog/draft-javascript-understanding-objects-vs-arrays-and-when-use-them-part-2